# How to add my styled mapbox vector maps to openlayers3

Tags: mapbox, openlayers-3

I tried using this example http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html

And it works well.

I have now styled my own map in Mapbox studio online.

I am not able to add my styled map in this example because there is a style function createMapboxStreetsV6Style() in the example which I am not able to get for my styles.

Any idea how I can add my styles mapbox vector map to openlayers 3?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The function is found here: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/examples/resources/mapbox-streets-v6-style.js

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible using [ol-mapbox-style](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/ol-mapbox-style/).

I've recently found an [issue](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/ol-mapbox-style/issues/8), however, it should not stop you from using this awesome package. I'm sure the maintainers will address that issue in no time.

Comment: Currently this is a link-only answer, can you add some details? A code sample, maybe?

Comment: @YuryFedorov the page that I've linked has a detailed code sample as well as a demo application. As the README states:
"To see the library in action, navigate to example/index.html"

Answer (score -2):

Depending on what you are using the map for, you can replace Openlayers for Mapbox-GL-JS as the maps will be much more fluid and better performing overall. Here's [an example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/examples/) to get you started if you're interested.

Otherwise, I'll point you to [one of the help guides on Mapbox.com](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mapbox-with-openlayers/) that walks through the steps to style a tile map and use it in Openlayers 3.0.

Hope this helps

**EDIT:** A better example to work off as an example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>OpenLayers MapBox Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.15.1/ol.js"></script>
  <link url="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.15.1/ol.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

```
var map = new ol.Map({
layers: [
new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    tileSize: [512, 512],
    url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v8/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=Your access token here'
  })
})
],
target: 'map',
view: new ol.View({
center: [0, 0],
zoom: 2
})
});
```

and lastly CSS:

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map { 
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; 
  bottom:0; 
  width:100%; 
}
```